# ViewController orientation change

Tags: iphone, navigation, orientation

I'm pushing a ViewController when the iPhone changes orientation to landscape and I'm having trouble with changing the orientation of the ViewController.

I used that code:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
Storage *strg = [Storage sharedStorage];

if ([strg.orient intValue] == 2) 
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:
     UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screen.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screen.bounds.size.height;
    UIView *navView = [[self navigationController] view];
    navView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    navView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    navView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57079633);
    navView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2.0, screenHeight/2.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
if ([strg.orient intValue] == 1)
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:
     UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

    UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
    CGFloat screenWidth = screen.bounds.size.width;
    CGFloat screenHeight = screen.bounds.size.height;
    UIView *navView = [[self navigationController] view];
    navView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenHeight, screenWidth);
    navView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    navView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(4.71238898);
    navView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth/2.0, screenHeight/2.0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
}
```

The result is not consistent; sometimes it goes into the right orientation and sometimes it's upside-down.

When I go from LandcapeRight to LandscapeLeft strait away (and vise versa) it works fine, the problem is only when I go to portrait mode.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really are responding to device orientation change they you probably shouldn't be using setStatusBarOrientation. I think you'd be better off making your viewcontrollers rotate to the supported orientations using shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation and deviceDidRotateSelector notifications.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(deviceDidRotateSelector:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object: nil];

-(void)deviceDidRotateSelector:(NSNotification*) notification {
// respond to rotation here
}


- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
//Return YES for supported orientations
return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'v tried this. wouldn't work. Don't know why, and I saw that a lot of others had this problem when combining orientation changes and navigation.

Comment: Hmm, well this works for me. The only issue I tend to have is making sure I respond to UIDeviceOrientationUnknown as well as the other orientations. However, I don't use nibs. I code everything, that might be why I don't have a problem. I still think you should avoid using setStatusBarOrientation as this doesn't actually change the device orientation - if you ask the device what it's device orientation is it will still say what it's real device orientation is even if you've set the status bar orientation to something else.

Comment: I don't know what i missed when i tried this before but now it works! Thanks!!